# When I submit a user login form, I want my webpage to be re-directed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I am working on building a website that has two pages. Homepage and admin panel page.

I am using a MERN stack.

Currently, when I click the admin link on my navigation bar it prompts the user for a username and passes and if the user types in the correct credentials then an alert pops up saying "welcome".(I used an alert to test if my onSubmit was working which it is.) Anyways the idea is I want the user to be redirected to my admin panel page upon clicking submit.

Things I've tried:

- upon successful credentials and submit, I tried returning my admin panel component
- upon successful credentials and submit, I tried returning a Link with a to="/admin" with react-router-dom

Things I think I need:

- a backend to retrieve a request? Like a post or a get request? I am not too familiar with backend stuff so I am unsure if I even need it to complete this.

Thank you, hope this was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are using React Router Dom, then you will have access to the **history** object in your component props.

Assuming your login component is something like this:

```
<h2>Login Here!</h2>
<Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.login}>
    Sign in
</Button>
```

Then after clicking on the sign-in button, `login` function will be called. And in the `login` function you could have something like this:

```
this.authenticateUser.then(() => {
     // do stuff you want to do after successful login
     this.props.history.push("/admin") // this is what you need
});
```

Make sure to wrap your component with `export default withRouter(LoginPage)` to get the access to `history` prop.

Don't forget to import `import {RouteComponentProps, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

Since I do not know how your code is like, this is the best I can come up with.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was actually looking into the history object , but I couldn't figure it out. This helped!

Comment: Glad It helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to redirect manually through `window.location = <url>` but if you are not using SSR or a backend with some routing solution , you need to make one, if you don't need SSR(server-side-rendering) consider adding routing to your express server.
supposing you are using React-Router following would be the code you need to use in your backend ( it's just a sample figure out something for yourself)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

// An api endpoint that returns a short list of items
app.get('/api/getList', (req,res) => {
    var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    res.json(list);
    console.log('Sent list of items');
});

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

Link for the explanation of source : [Deploying a React app with React-Router and an Express Backend](https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3)!

Comment: Thank you for the example and the link. I am interested in getting this working with a backend that has routes.